# Format new data entered into text field

Tags: jquery, forms

```
    // capture selling price change 
$('#frmFilters').on('change', 'input[name="sell[]"]', function() {

    // define the tr that we want to pull form values from
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');

    // set up values for form fields to pass through to ajax call
    var sell = row.find('.sell').val();

    var pkID = row.find('.lineup').val();

    var sku = (row.find('.sku').map(function(){
        return this.name + '=' + this.value;
    }).get().join('&'));

    // do ajax call
    $.ajax({ ... });

})
```

From the above code I want to format the price entered into the text field name = sell[] which also has a class of sell to always have 2 decimal points

How can I achieve this please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the javascript function `toFixed(2)` so that it always has two decimal

```
$('#frmFilters').on('change', 'input[name="sell[]"]', function() {

   var numericVal = parseInt(this.value, 10);
   numericVal = numericVal.toFixed(2);
   //set the value of the input field to the formatted value
    this.value=numericVal;
})
```

EDIT - fiddle here with multiple fields http://jsfiddle.net/LtR9N/2/

Comment: thanks, how do I target the changed form field to apply this ?

Comment: @I-CRE8 i use the `this` keyword that in this case refers to the input field that originated the event. Look at the fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LtR9N/1/

Comment: I understand how to get the value using `this` but what I need is for the value in the text field to change as well so if I enter 3 for example I want the text field to display 3.00

Comment: @I-CRE8  Ah, ok, just add `this.value=numericVal;` updated fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/LtR9N/2/

Comment: excellent thank you, it was the `.value` part that I was missing in my efforts previously logged for future reference